# No entiendo como resolver

Tags: python, tkinter

MI codigo es programa que guarda, busca y edita inventario. Estoy intentando usar **TKINTER** para poder crear una interfaz. Pero tengo un problema al intentar juntar ambas. Las funciones sin **TKINTER** funcionan pero al intentar juntarlos estoy con algunos problemas. La verdad no sabria que parte estaria mal como tal. Por ello muestor el codigo entero.

EL CODIGO ES MAS LARGO PERO CREO QUE ESTO ES MAS QUE SUFICIENTE

```
import pickle
import tkinter
def main():
   def nuevaven1(): #Agregar objeto a diccionario
       ventana.withdraw()
       win=tkinter.Toplevel()
       win.geometry('520x350')
       codigoas=tkinter.Label(win, text="Ingrese Codigo:",width=30)
       codigoas.place(x=20,y=30)
       codigoen=tkinter.Entry(win, text="",width=30)
       codigoen.place(x=300,y=30)

       descripcio=tkinter.Label(win, text="Ingrese Descripcion:",width=30)
       descripcio.place(x=20,y=70)
       descripcioen=tkinter.Entry(win, text="",width=30)
       descripcioen.place(x=300,y=70)

       cantidad=tkinter.Label(win, text="Ingrese cantidad:",width=30)
       cantidad.place(x=20,y=110)
       cantidaden=tkinter.Entry(win, text="",width=30)
       cantidaden.place(x=300,y=110)
       def agregar(dic):
           x = codigoen.get()
           y = descripcioen.get()
           z = cantidaden.get()
           dic[x] =[y,z]

       confirmar=tkinter.Button(win, text="Confirmar",width=30,command=agregar)
       confirmar.place(x=290,y=150)


   ventana =tkinter.Tk()
   ventana.config(bg='#CBE0F3')
   ventana.geometry('520x350')
   ventana.resizable(0,0)
   ventana.title('Inversan')
   agregarb=tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Agregar",width=30,command=nuevaven1)
   agregarb.place(x=290,y=150,)
   editarb=tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Editar",width=30)
   editarb.place(x=290,y=210)
   buscarb=tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Buscar",width=30)
   buscarb.place(x=290,y=270)
   ventana.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Como vieron algunas partes solo funcionan con funciones pero esta en trabajo solo queiro saber como arreglar mi error que esta en la funcion **nuevaven1** y en la funcion **agregar**.

**FUNCIONA LA INTERFAZ DE TKINTER** pero al ingresar datos a la funcion **agregar** y guardar los datos suelta un error. Nose porque o como arreglarlo
Este es mi código pero tengo un error que es el siguiente:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pedro Santos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: agregar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dic'
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que has definido tu función `agregar` con un argumento no opcional.

```
def agregar(dic):
    x = codigoen.get()
    y = descripcioen.get()
    z = cantidaden.get()
    dic[x] =[y,z]
```

Y el callback de tu botón `confirmar` no está mandando dicho argumento `dic`:

```
confirmar=tkinter.Button(win, text="Confirmar",width=30,command=agregar)
```

Lo que puedes hacer es definir tu diccionario en algún otro lugar y modificar `agregar` para no tomar argumentos (o dejar `dic` con un default).

Definir `diccionario` en algún lugar:

```
buscarb=tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Buscar",width=30)
buscarb.place(x=290,y=270)
diccionario = {}  # Nuevo!
ventana.mainloop()
```

Y usar `diccionario` en la función agregar:

```
def agregar():
    x = codigoen.get()
    y = descripcioen.get()
    z = cantidaden.get()
    diccionario[x] =[y,z]
```

Eso debería ayudarte a que funcione el código. Supongo que después deberías analizar el mejor sitio para definir cada variable.